# Android Spinner visibility not updating

Tags: android, spinner

I have 5 spinners that all depend on each other. Basically one is "country", other is "province" other is "city"...etc

They are being populated based on a database. If the database is empty (example, if there are no cities found under that province) that spinner should be hidden with no values. For some reason, it will only update on the display when the screen "rotates". This is how I am doing it now:

```
structure.spinner.setAdapter(null);
structure.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
structure.textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you show some more context of where this code is? And what is `structure`?

Comment: Can you explain more what you needed.,

Comment: It sounds like your database queries and subsequent UI updates are only being performed in the activity's **onCreate** method, which is why it works when your orientation changes. Trigger these operations as needed. I can't be more specific until you post more information.